# npm run build on multiple environments without mention specified environment

Tags: angular, npm

I am using angular project with multiple environment. Whenever doing build taking so long time for single environment. How can i reduce it. I have added my project configuration here.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=10240 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --aot",
    "build": "rimraf dist && node --max_old_space_size=10240 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:universal": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:universal": "node dist/server.js",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "postbuild": "node zipbuild"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "7.3.3",
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/cli": "7.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.6",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "7.0.0-beta.23",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.6",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.6",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "7.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.6",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.2.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^11.9.5",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "css-loader": "2.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.0.2",
    "tslint": "^5.13.0",
    "typescript": "3.2.4"
  }
}
```

angular.json:

```
    {
      "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
      "version": 1,
      "newProjectRoot": "projects",
      "projects": {
        "test": {
          "root": "",
          "sourceRoot": "src",
          "projectType": "application",
          "architect": {
            "build": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
              "options": {
                "outputPath": "dist",
                "index": "src/index.html",
                "main": "src/main.ts",
                "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                "assets": [
                  "src/assets",
                  "src/favicon.ico",
                  "src/web.config"
                ],
                "styles": [
                  "src/styles.scss"
                ],
                "scripts": [
                  "src/assets/SigWebTablet.js"
                ]
              },
              "configurations": {
                "demo": {
                  "optimization": true,
                  "outputHashing": "all",
                  "sourceMap": false,
                  "extractCss": true,
                  "namedChunks": false,
                  "aot": true,
                  "extractLicenses": true,
                  "vendorChunk": false,
                  "buildOptimizer": true,
                  "outputPath": "dist/demo",
                  "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                      "with": "src/environments/environment.demo.ts"
                    }
                  ]
                },
"demo1": {
                  "optimization": true,
                  "outputHashing": "all",
                  "sourceMap": false,
                  "extractCss": true,
                  "namedChunks": false,
                  "aot": true,
                  "extractLicenses": true,
                  "vendorChunk": false,
                  "buildOptimizer": true,
                  "outputPath": "dist/demo",
                  "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                      "with": "src/environments/environment.demo.ts"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "serve": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "test:build"
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "browserTarget": "test:build:production"
                },
                "sacramento": {
                  "browserTarget": "test:build:sacramento"
                },
                "denver": {
                  "browserTarget": "test:build:denver"
                },
                "orange": {
                  "browserTarget": "test:build:orange"
                },
                "slo": {
                  "browserTarget": "test:build:slo"
                }
              }
            },
            "extract-i18n": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "atims-prebook:build"
              }
            },
            "test": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
              "options": {
                "main": "src/test.ts",
                "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
                "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                "scripts": [],
                "styles": [
                  "src/styles.scss"
                ],
                "assets": [
                  "src/assets",
                  "src/favicon.ico"
                ]
              }
            },
            "lint": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
              "options": {
                "tsConfig": [
                  "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                  "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                ],
                "exclude": [
                  "**/node_modules/**"
                ]
              }
            },
            "server": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
              "options": {
                "outputPath": "dist/server",
                "main": "main.server.ts",
                "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "test-e2e": {
          "root": "",
          "sourceRoot": "e2e",
          "projectType": "application",
          "architect": {
            "e2e": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
              "options": {
                "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
                "devServerTarget": "test:serve"
              }
            },
            "lint": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
              "options": {
                "tsConfig": [
                  "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
                ],
                "exclude": [
                  "**/node_modules/**"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "defaultProject": "test",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:class": {
          "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "spec": false,
          "prefix": "pbpc",
          "styleext": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "spec": false,
          "prefix": "pbpc"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:guard": {
          "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:module": {
          "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
          "spec": false
        }
      }
    }
```

I am using command to build is "**npm run build -- --c demo**" & "**npm run build -- --c demo1**" to build in separate command prompt. For each single build is approximately taking 20 to 30min. Do we have any option to build in single query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can execute commands together, like so:

```
npm run build -- --c demo && npm run build -- --c demo1
```

Or you can specify your own command, using package json scripts:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.13.0",
    "npm": "6.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest src/app",
    "test:watch": "jest src/app --watch",
    "lint": "tslint -c tslint.json 'src/app/**/*.ts' --project src/tsconfig.json",
    "appStart": "npm run build -- --c demo && npm run build -- --c demo1" // This line
  },
}
```

Then simply run

```
npm run appStart
```

**Note:**

There are more options to use, for executing multiple commands together, here is a **cheatsheet**:

```
A; B    # Run A and then B, regardless of success of A
A && B  # Run B if and only if A succeeded
A || B  # Run B if and only if A failed
A &     # Run A in background.
```

Comment: thank you. It works like charm. I would like to know, is it possible to build only one environment and can we change configuration setup in built files for remaining environments. Because, for single build itself taking 30min. Is there any solution for that? I am expecting like ASP.NET publish procedure.

Comment: Glad I could help (: Not sure I follow your questions. Possible to build only one env = yes. Change configuration setup in build files = Not sure I understand. The time it's taking you to build = seems like a new question you would have to ask, and supply more information. A build should not normally take so long.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I will ask as new question.

Comment: Sure, sorry I can't help here, it seems there is not enough information to resolve why the build is taking long, there could be several reasons. If this answer resolved your original question, please accept it

Comment: @venkateswaran R I need the same one single build that should work based on dynamic value from deployed environment. I don't want to take separate build for each environment. Did you get any info regarding this??

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Node.js program to run multiple commands in parallel using child_process and Promise.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).